# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error cannot find parameter

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, soap-api-v2

I am using SOAP api to integrate an ERP system but throws fatal error **Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error cannot find parameter**

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$api_url_v2 = "https://ninobambino.in/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1";

$username = 'test123';
$password = 'test123';

$cli = new SoapClient($api_url_v2);

//retreive session id from login
//$session_id = $cli->login($username, $password);
$session = $cli->login('test123', 'test123');

//call customer.list method
$result = $cli->customerCustomerList($session_id);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: try with $session = $cli->login((object)array('username' => 'test123', 'apiKey' => 'test123'));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is when you pass session to get customer list **$result = $cli->customerCustomerList($session_id);**

Now change to following code:

```
<?php
$api_url_v2 = "https://ninobambino.in/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl";

$username = 'test123';
$password = 'test123';

$cli = new SoapClient($api_url_v2);

//retreive session id from login
//$session_id = $cli->login($username, $password);
$session = $cli->login('test123', 'test123');

//call customer.list method
$result = $cli->customerCustomerList($session);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now **Magento SOAP API** have updated logic for get **session ID** using login method. Try below mentioned code.

```
try{

  $wsdlUrl = 'https://www.yourdomain.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl';
  $client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl);
  // $sessionId = $client->login("******","******");
  $auth_resp = $client->login(array("username"=>"Your username","apiKey"=>"API key"));
  $sessionId = $auth_resp->result;    
}catch(Exception $e){
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($e);
  exit;
}

echo $sessionId;exit;
```